# Rxswift cancel observer when an event happen and resubcribe

Tags: ios, swift, observable, rx-swift

Hi anyone knows how to cancel the observable when an event happens and resubscribe (basically I want an observable to skip emitting when another event happens (Cancel button tap)

Detail scenario: Cancel button is tapped on a `UISearchBar`, how to make observable to pause and stop emitting event when the Cancel button is tapped?

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
Observable.of(searchClick,historyClick).merge().debounce(0.3, scheduler: scheduler)
                    .takeUntil(searchBar.rx.cancelButtonClicked)
                    .bind(to: viewModel.search)
                    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

but the subscription is stopped after that. How can we resubscribe or any other way to skip emitting when an event happens?

Comment: What you have makes the observable stop emitting when the cancel button is clicked. What's supposed to get it to start again?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is better to switch to the next observable (which may be dormant at the time of the switch) using '*.switchLatest()*' operator.

```swift
let eventSwitch: BehaviorSubject<Observable<T>> = BehaviorSubject.create(/*initial value*/) // where T is your type of choice
let events = eventSwitch.switchLatest() // subscribe consumer to this
eventSwitch.onNext(/*new event source of type Observable<T>*/) // call this from "Cancel" button
```

**UPDATE**

```swift
let eventSwitch = BehaviorSubject(value: Observable
    .of(searchClick,historyClick)
    .merge()
    .debounce(0.3, scheduler: scheduler)
  )
let events = eventSwitch.switchLatest()

events
  .bind(to: viewModel.search)
  .disposed(by: disposeBag)

// call this from "Cancel" button
eventSwitch.onNext(...)
// argument can be empty observable or 'Observable.of(searchClick,historyClick).merge().debounce(0.3, scheduler: scheduler)'
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Can u elaborate in more detail? how can we prevent this observable to happen when cancel is click: Observable.of(searchClick,historyClick).merge().debounce(0.3, scheduler: scheduler)

Comment: Once you provide another observable (even an empty one!) in 'eventSwitch.onNext(...)', the subscriber will be unsubscribed from the previous observable. In your case, the main subscription will look like 'events.bind(to: viewModel.search).disposed(by: disposeBag)' - see update.

Comment: Can help check the syntax of the first let. Getting the error: Cannot convert value of type 'Observable<String>' to expected argument type '(AnyObserver<_>) -> Disposable'

Comment: hi apply our suggest but the observable still fire when cancel button is clicked. We went to skip fire when cancel is clicked

Comment: After you have called 'eventSwitch.onNext(Observable.empty())'?

Comment: Hi if i use eventSwitch.onNext(Observable.empty()). when click observable does not fire but the rather completely stop. if i use eventSwitch.onNext(Observable.of...) then cancel button still fire main observable

Comment: Perhaps '.pausable()' operator from https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwiftExt is a better option for you then.